# How can I use x-editable and jquery validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, x-editable

### How can i validate information using [jquery validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) plugin when using [XEDITABLE](https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable) for edit-in-place?

**This is my current non-validated x-editable field**

[image]

**This is what i pretend**

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I use [valib.js](http://www.sideralis.org/valib/) instead of stone  jquery validation

**HTML:**

```
<p>X-editable Bootstrap popup</p>
<div style="margin: 150px">
    <a href="#" id="email">awesome</a>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#email').editable({
    type: 'text',
    url: '/post',    
    pk: 1,    
    placement: 'top',
    title: 'Enter email' ,
    validate:function(value){

       var v=valib.String.isEmailLike(value)         
       if(v==false) return 'Please insert valid mail';
    }   
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/maksa9/6vzh501k/)

Answer (score 2):

**Currently the use of jQuery Validation Plugin is not supported by X-editable.**

jQuery Validation Plugin has two requirements that doesn't play well with most implementations of X-editable:

1. It requires the validated element to be a child of a `<form>` element ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26204366/1513222)).
   In theory, we could have workaround this by nesting the x-editable fields inside a `<form></form>` element, **but**:
2. The validated elements **must** be form elements (`<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<select>`, etc...) ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6617935/1513222))

So basically, here are your options:

1. Use the [HTML5 input types feature](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#html5types) by setting the field attribute `data-type='email'` ([see demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/itailulu/wx38rz5L/882/))
   The output will be slightly different from what you expected it to be, according to your screenshot. Therefore you should probably use one of the following methods, which is:
2. Use another external validation library, like @dm4web suggested.
3. Ultimately you can also create your own validation function if your prefer, [see demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/itailulu/qws6qnw6/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Based on answer above but an attempt to use jquery validation.
From

**HTML**

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('#email').editable({
    type: 'text',
    url: '/post',    
    pk: 1,    
    placement: 'top',
    title: 'Enter email' ,
    validate: function(value){
       var flag = $("#email-input").validate();
       if (!flag) {
          return 'Please insert valid mail';
       }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It support have data-type='email' as well.

HTML5 input types. Following types are supported:

password,
email,
url,
tel,
number,
range,
time

```
<a href="#" id="email" data-type="email" data-
pk="1">admin@example.com</a>
<script>
 $(function(){
  $('#email').editable({
    url: '/post',
    title: 'Enter email'
    });
  });
</script>
```