# jquery or javascript method to add validations to input tags before submitting the page

Tags: jquery, validation

I have the below snippet of input tags which are not server controls so unable to use required field validators. So i want to use validators using jquery or java script.Can anyone help me with this.

```
   <div id="win">
        <table>
           <tr>
             <td>
               <div>
             <label id="lblname" for="Name"(required)>Name</label>
           </div>
              <div  id="dname">
               <input data-bind="value: data.Name" id="inpName" />
              </div>
         </td>
             <td>
               <div>
             <label id="lblend" for="End"(required)>End</label>
           </div>
              <div  id="dend">
               <input data-bind="value: data.end"  />
              </div>
         </td>

       </tr>
     </table>
    </div>


    <script>
    $("#win").validate();
        </script>
```

tried using this but didnt work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Here](https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/) is an example for what you are looking

You have to put the things to be validated in a form tag not in a div. Replace the

`<div id="win">`
 with a

```
<form id="win">
```

Comment: Without using form cant we do it

Comment: Yes you cant see the [The Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487430/validate-inputs-that-are-not-inside-a-form-with-jquery-validation-plugin) and the answer whichs says It is not possible.

Comment: Got it by using the below code but after clicking ok on alert the page is submitting 'if ($("#inpname").val() == "") {
                alert("Please enter name");
                  return false;'

Comment: Great that my solution worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

After trying several option got this working .might help someone.

```
if ($("#inpName").val() == "" ) {
            alert("Please enter EndBy");
            e.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use HTML5's `required` attribute, like so:

`<input data-bind="value: data.Name" required>`

But since it' HTML5 it's not supported by all browsers, you can see the list [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp). Good luck.

EDIT: Yes, I missed to state that your inputs should be inside a `<form>` and the validation will be performed on its submit.

Comment: Try to wrap your inputs with a `form` element.

Comment: Got it by using the below code but after clicking ok on alert the page is submitting 'if ($("#inpname").val() == "") {
                alert("Please enter name");
                  return false;'